# Spring Amqp annotations based

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am new to Spring AMQP and want to use annotation based configuration for both producers and consumers using latest spring amqp 1.5.4 ,

Is there any pseoudo code available for configuration which does the logic for creating connection or @Queue etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the quickest way to get started would be use [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-amqp) - boot will create all the beans you need (connecting to localhost by default but easily overridable with properties).

You can also look at some of the [Spring AMQP test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/EnableRabbitIntegrationTests.java).

Answer (score 0):

Have a class annotated with @Configuration in Spring Boot which can provide you with annotation based bean definition :
Here is a sample :

```
@Configuration
public class QueueConfig {

@Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }
@Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setExchange("myQueue");
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

@Bean
    Queue rabbitQueue() {
        return new Queue(WORKERS_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    }
}
```